# In React-Native the TextInput field wont allow me to edit or type new text

Tags: react-native, textinput

I noticed when I would try to type anything in the text input field it would automatically delete it. I have narrowed down to the problem being the value field and commenting it out allows me to input text but I am not sure what could be the issue.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState('');

  const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
    setEnteredGoal(enteredGoal);
  };

  const addGoalHandler = () => {
    console.log(enteredGoal);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder="Course Goal"
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
          value={enteredGoal}
        />
        <Button title='Add' onPress={addGoalHandler} />
      </View>
      <View />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument in `goalInputHandler()`, `enteredText` does not match the parameter in `setEnteredGoal()`, `enteredGoal`.

Correct code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState('');

  const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => (
    setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
  );

  const addGoalHandler = () => (
    console.log(enteredGoal);
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder="Course Goal"
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
          value={enteredGoal}
        />
        <Button title='Add' onPress={addGoalHandler} />
      </View>
      <View />
    </View>
  );
}
```